# How to make multiple requests when testing endpoints with JWT auth

Tags: laravel, jwt

I have to test an endpoint which requires a logged in user. Since I'm using JWT, I'm authenticating the user like this:

```php
    return $this->postJson($uri, $data, [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . JWTAuth::fromUser($user),
    ]);
```

Everything is fine, the user is successfully logged in, and I can reach the endpoint. The problem is, that if I want to make another request, the jwt-auth implementation caches the user. In a result of that, the expression in the following if is never reached (which is on my endpoint):

```php
    if (auth()->user()->avatar) {
        $this->deleteImageService->delete(auth()->user()->avatar);
    }
```

I've checked and the user is definitely the same in each request. Here is the test method, and the reason of why I need to make two consequent requests:

```php
    /** @test */
    public function if_avatar_already_exists_it_is_replaced_by_the_new_avatar()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $avatar = UploadedFile::fake()->image('test.jpg');

        $firstAvatarUrl = $this->postJson($avatar, $user)->json('avatar_url');

        $this->assertEquals($firstAvatarUrl, $user->avatar->url());
        $this->assertEquals(1, Image::count());

        $secondAvatarUrl = $this->postJson($avatar, $user)->json('avatar_url');

        $this->assertEquals($secondAvatarUrl, $user->load('avatar')->avatar->url());
        $this->assertEquals(1, Image::count());
    }
```

Comment: Did you use `actingAs($user)` method before sending request instead of set token in header?

Comment: This is not applicable because the token-based authentication doesn't use sessions.

Comment: @NikolayTraykov The `actingAs()` method, as well as the whole build-in Authentication doesn't support stateful drivers only. So you should indeed use `actingAs` here. Another thing I would try is to call `$user->fresh()` before passing it to the second request. Or check the jwt library for a similar method, ie to force bust the cache. I am just blindly giving suggestions, tho. Haven't really faced the issue. Btw, the argument in all your `postJson` calls looks off to me. Maybe I am missing something, but you could double check them as well.

Comment: Ok, I saw the `actingAs` method, it definitely works as you both said. Apologize! Unfortunately in my service, the user cannot retrieve the avatar relation since it's cached. I need to call  $this->user->load('avatar')->avatar, which is not good because I do it only because of the test.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the test. I don't call the $user->avatar in the test, and I refresh the user model before the second request. Now by using actingAs, at least I'm sure that the user model is the same in the test as it's in the service. Also, by calling actingAs, the code is cleaner. Thanks a lot!